# Set flexible width textfield in Toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

I am working on an app. The xcode version is 9 and the iOS version is 11. The project is in objective c.

I want to add a toolbar in the app that contains a textfield and button. The problem is the both the items are works properly in portrait mode but for landscape mode the width of textfield and button is not adjusted automatically to fill the whole toolbar.

One thing that i have noticed that we can't be able to add the constraints on the bar items. I already try the flexible width and fixed width to set the dynamic width of both items but noenter image description here solution worked for me. So Please suggest me what can i do to set the flexible width of textfield and button that are in a toolbar in landscape mode. Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot of what i get in landscape mode]

[image: Screenshort of what i want to display on view]

Comment: try setting `contentHuggingPriority` of the `textField` to 1.. it's just a guess, but it might work

Comment: Thanks for help. Can you please  give me more detail on contentHuggingPriority that how can i use it in my app. As i search about it i relates to constraints but i already mentioned that we can't be able to add the constraints on the bar items.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622485-setcontenthuggingpriority

Comment: contentHuggingPriority is not working

Comment: well, lets try another guess -  try to add a constraint to set the width of the textField to constant of size 1000 (super big) with a priority set to e.g. 10. Thus it will not force this size, but it will try to fulfil it while not breaking the layout.. if that don't work, try to change the priority, maybe to 999 (not 1000, that is a required constraint) to see if that is the way

Comment: Sorry but i told that i'm not able to add constraints on the textfield that is placed in a toolbar So how can i try to implement your suggestion??

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. can you add the code to the question, so that we can try it out ourselves?

Comment: Actually i'm not implemented it programmatically . i have just add toolbar on the bottom of view. Set constraints over it. Then add the textfield and button into the tool bar thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I try to implement multiple things to set the flexible width of textfield and found the solution. we need to just add the code of one line and it works like charm. Add the top, left and right constraints to the toolbar, add the fixed height constraint for toolbar and connect the textfield outlet.

`txtfld.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;`